# referencing global variables from inline assembly in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, undefined-reference

I have the problem where the linker generates undefined reference errors
from the inline assembly code.

```
int global_var = 0;
void myfunc()
{
    asm(".intel_syntax noprefix\n");
    asm("lea eax, global_var\n");
}
```

I am compiling with -masm=intel and with no optimizations or anything, using GCC 3.4.2
If anyone suffered from this inconvenience too please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it's an issue of *name mangling* - that is to say, the compiler mangles(alters) the names of variables and functions during the compile phase. In this instance, "global_var" is altered to "_global_var"

If you change the 2nd line of your function such that it accesses "_global_var" then it compiles just fine. (tested GCC 4.7.1)

Comment: Ugh thanks man! 
I forgot that minGW does this, it does not happen under Linux.